# using mathf.clamp as boundary for different size of screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i currently have a gameobject named "block" with two long cubes next to each other with a gap between them. now when a user touches the screen and drags left or right the block also moves in that direction. now i am trying to setup a boundary so they can go up to a certain amount in the left or right direction. however how  can i code this so it is the same for different screens eg iphone ipad etc.

the code i am currently using makes the block overlap each other getting rid of the gap which needs to be there. how do i go about to fix this. the code is below:

```
 public float speed = 0.0F;
 void Update() {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
        // Get movement of the finger since last frame
        Vector3 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

        // Move object across XY plane
        transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, 0, 0);

        Vector3 boundaryVector = transform.position;   
        boundaryVector.x = Mathf.Clamp (boundaryVector.x, -1f, 1f);
        transform.position = boundaryVector;
    }
}
```

[image: blocks in unity]

Answer (score 1):

For screen size problem I recommend u put some Image Ui at the background and then according to different resolution set it Using `anchor` property and .

Make height to width ratio 0.5,Set UI scale to screen size...all these in `Inspector` Only.
Get the left and right boundary values from `Transform` and then in `block` gameobj script use it as follows :

```
//windows specific code

            float x=Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
            if (x == 0) {
                Stop ();
            } else if (x > 0) {
                MoveRight ();
            } else if (x < 0) {
                MoveLeft ();
            }
            pos = transform.position;      //left                   //right
            pos.x=Mathf.Clamp (pos.x, "your boundry min to", "Your boundry max");
            transform.position = pos;
```

for overlap problem u can make use of Parent/ child property in Block .Make one the child of another..in this way If u move left the right block will also move left and they will not overlap....

Comment: i have done the following as you have asked, however when i paste the above code in my block gameobject im getting error CS0103: The name `pos' does not exist in the current context. this is for "Stop", "moveright","moveleft","pos" and so on. as im fairly new to unity and c# could you explain why these errors are occuring and how i can resolve this problem. thanks

Comment: first u learn c#..and basics of unity from google. In this case u got these errors due to no declaration of the variable `pos`   Declare it in class